# Como salvar dados passados por parâmetro na url em uma session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

É o seguinte, me foi pedido para fazer isso: Fazer com que o usuário possa passar por parametro na url a imagem e a cor desejada(para mudar a imagem e a cor de acordo com o cliente), no momento que receber esta cor e imagem,devo gravar em sessão (session) por cliente para que não percamos a referencia de imagem e cor quando navegarmos na janela.

Comment: `$_SESSION['cor'] = $_GET['cor'];` ?

Comment: Verifique se por exemplo `$_GET['cor']` existe caso faça a atribuição em `$_SESSION`

Comment: session_start();
 if (isset($_GET['cor'], ) $_GET['imagem']) { //a verificação assim? e pra fazer a atribuição?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Você pode usar a seguinte maneira:**

```
//Iniciamos a sessão
session_start("customizacao");
//Armazenamos seus valores
$_SESSION['imagem'] = isset($_GET['variavel_imagem']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'variavel_imagem') : 'imagem_padrao';
$_SESSION['cor'] = isset($_GET['variavel_cor']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'variavel_cor') : 'azul';
```

**Usar ela:**

```
echo $_SESSION['cor']; ou $cor = $_SESSION['cor'];
```

**Destruindo uma sessão:**

```
session_destroy();
```

**Apagar uma varíavel específica:**

```
unset($_SESSION['cor']);
```

---

**Exemplo para Code Igniter (pedido do usuário)**

```
//Ou utilize a forma proposta pelo code igniter para obter valores
$cor = isset($_GET['variavel_cor']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'variavel_cor') : 'azul';
$imagem = isset($_GET['variavel_imagem']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'variavel_imagem') : 'imagem_padrao';
$this->session->set_userdata('cor', $cor);
$this->session->set_userdata('imagem', $imagem);
```

**Referências:**

[Documentação Oficial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)
[Documentação Traduzida](https://web.archive.org/web/20180220082937/http://www.plasmadesign.com.br:80/codeigniter/user_guide-pt_BR/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Opa, valeu! Sabe como eu poderia fazer usando isso o session do CodeIgneter? "$this->session->"

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann Feito, não uso code ignitor... mas acredito que seja isso ai, ou você pode passar um array também. Vide: http://www.plasmadesign.com.br/codeigniter/user_guide-pt_BR/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Valeu mano, muito obrigado! Estou começando na programação agora e ainda tenho essas dificuldades. Ajudou muito!

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann disponha...

Comment: @MarceloDiniz obrigado, vou incluir a oficial nas referências.

Comment: Rafael,assim estaria correto? session_start();
 if(isset($_GET['color'], $_GET['image'])) {
 $color = $_GET['color'];
 $image = $_GET['image'];
 $this->session->set_userdata('color', $color);
 $this->session->set_userdata('image', $image);

  }

Comment: Você pode usar assim `$imagem = isset($_GET['image']) ? $_GET['image'] : 'imagem_padrao'; $this->session->set_userdata('image', $imagem);` Está ali no exemplo... Não esqueça de tratar os parâmetros recebidos.

Comment: Mas apenas para mim entender, estaria correto também?

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann acredito que sim... :)

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi a parte de tratas os parâmetros recebidos...

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann ah desculpe, esqueci que elas não vão para o banco... então não precisa se preocupar com isso.

Comment: Ah ok! Muito obrigado mesmo, estou programando a menos de um mês e realmente me ajudou muito!

Comment: @GuilhermeWermann fique a vontade... sempre que tiver dúvidas relacionadas a programação coloque aqui no stack :)